# How to remove duplicates from list of objects by id

Tags: java

could you please tell me..

> How to remove duplicates from list of objects by id In java

Comment: could you please show us your effort so far...

Comment: Add Objects into `Set` which doesn't allow duplicates

Comment: or dont put the duplicates in in the first place.

Comment: How are we supposed to help if you don't show any effort in solving the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Hi RaodRunner, i am doing like this... ....                            
  ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
     list .add("abc");
     list .add('a');
    list .add('b');
     list .add('a');
     list .add("abc");
    list .add('c');
     list .add(10);
     list .add("abc");
     list .add(10);
     
     for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
         for(int j=i+1;j<list.size();j++){
             if(list.get(i).equals(list.get(j))){
                 list.remove(j);
                 j--;
             }
         }
     }
    
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(int id=0;i<list.size();i++)
  {
   object = list.get(i);

     for(int j; j<list.size();j++)
     {

       object1 = list.get(j);

          if(object == object1 && id != j){
          list.remove(j);
      }
   }


}
```

Comment: HI Spp93 could please brief me How you are doing complete so that i can get understand

Comment: match each item of outer loop with every item of inner loop and if item matches but their IDs are different simply remove the item.